# Where does adduser's Directory Information Go?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, user-management, user-accounts

When I use the command `adduser` it asks me for all sorts of directory-like information such as:

- Full Name
- Room Number
- Work Phone
- etc.

Where is this information stored and how does one retrieve or edit it? It might be useful to add that this machine *isn't* connected to an LDAP or NIS server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These informations are stored in `/etc/passwd` :

```
myuser:x:1001:1001:My User,Room,8888888888,9999999999,Other:/home/myuser:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Oh, there it is! Is there a standard utility to edit and retrieve this data? Also, in the age of LDAP, is this information actually used anywhere?

Comment: `Bash` or `Shell` are the most standard utility ! You can install [finger](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_finger.htm) if you want but i cannot see what will be the benefit. I am not sure in case of a pam_ldap authentication...

Comment: The full name may be used by mail client running locally on that system.  There are a few other minor tools that might try to use the gecos information.  It is mostly pointless though.

Comment: If it's mostly pointless, is it safe to say that most administrators leave this information blank?